# How to get only a single output of the result in python program?

Tags: python, loops, primes

I was writing a code in python to identify prime number. Here is the code

```
n=int(input("Enter any integer"))
for i in range(2,n,1):
   if n%i==0:
       print(n, " is not a prime number")
       break
   else:
       print("Prime number")
```

But the problem is that I am getting "Prime number" as an output for each time the else condition is activated. I am attaching the output results too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1bco.png)

I want to have a single "Prime number" written as an output if the number is prime. How can I get there?

I tried to use `continue` inside the `else` .

```
n=int(input("Enter any integer"))
for i in range(2,n,1):
   if n%i==0:
       print(n, " is not a prime number")
       break
   else:
       continue
```

If the number is prime there is no output. But I want "Prime number" written as my output if the number is prime.

Then I tried to apply `for` `else` condition.

It did work though but I want to know how to stop the multiple "prime number" printing of my previous code.

Comment: "I also tried to apply for else condition but didn't work." To explain that, we would have to see that attempt.

Comment: Try adding a flag outside the `for` loop indicating whether the number is currently known to be prime. And if someone tells you to use the for-else syntax, *don't, it's evil*.

Comment: You need to distinguish whether the loop is exited via the break statement, or whether it runs to completion.  In the former case, the number is composite.  In the latter, it's prime.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `11 mod i` and see if any of them are equal to 0 `[11%i for i in range(2,11,1)]`

Comment: @Fractalism Can you explain a little about this flag thing? I am really a beginner in python.

Comment: @TomKarzes When I am using [for] [else] condition, it's working fine. But is there someway so that I can stop this continuous printing of "prime number" due to the loop from my previous code?

Comment: @SoumyadeepChakraborty It is exactly like in Tom Karzes's answer.

Comment: @Fractalism Now I get it. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it like this:

```
n=int(input("Enter any integer"))

is_prime = True
for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i==0:
        is_prime = False
        break

if is_prime:
    print(n, " is a prime number")
else:
    print(n, " is not a prime number")
```

This sets the variable `is_prime` to `False` if any divisor is found, exiting the loop immediately. If the loop runs to completion, then no divisor was found.

Note that this could be sped up in a couple ways:

1. After checking if 2 is a divisor, you could skip the remaining even numbers and only check for odd divisors.
2. The loop doesn't need to run all the way up to `n-1`.  Once `i` exceeds the square root of `n`, if no divisor has been found, then `n` is prime and the loop can exit.

But it should function correctly with this fix.

Comment: Thanks for your generous help. I get to understand it properly. I will keep this in my mind. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Every time `n%i` is not equal to 0, the else statement runs.
To fix this, you can remove the else statement entirely and just stop the code after the if statement runs. For example, you can do this like this:
`for i in range(2,n,1): if n%i==0: print(n, " is not a prime number") exit() print(f"{n} is a prime number")`

Comment: Thanks for your kind guidance. It worked. I did similar coding using for else. But can you spare a little time to explain me about a way through which I can get only the last output of the else loop printed in my previous code?

Comment: You cannot just delete outputs but you can try just adding them to a list and printing one of them.

Comment: Tip: You can use triple backticks instead of single backtick around the code so it doesn't all get cramped in one line.

Comment: @Tauman That is actually clever one. I will remember this for my future codes. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @Fractalism What is backtick?

Comment: It's to the left of the 1 key.

Comment: Also the other ones are better for integrating this to larger scripts as they do not finish the execution. @SoumyadeepChakraborty

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this (like terminating the program early, or saving to a variable to check on later, etc), but i think the one you are looking for is the for else clause.

```
n=int(input("Enter any integer"))
for i in range(2,n,1):
    if n%i==0:
       print(n, " is not a prime number")
       break
else:
   print("Prime number")
```

and yes, this is exactly like your code but with the else unindented. That Else statment that comes after the for loop basically means "Run this if the loop didn't break, and skip it otherwise".

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this to me. Now I get to know how the computer thinks in this case. But as you have said that there are multiple ways to do so, can you share another example where there is an indented else loop but only prints a single "prime number" output without repeating it multiple times?

Comment: Using the for-else syntax is probably a bad idea - [Python's creator wishes this feature never existed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Im38sF-sjo)